# Распознать брейкпойнты градиента в изображении

Tags: css3, градиент, html, css

Имеется картинка-изображение (фон кнопки в png). Представляет собой линейный вертикальный градиент с несколькими брейкпойнтами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить эти брейкпойнты (цвет и процент). Ну пипеткой и на глаз понятно как сделать :)

Я более чем уверен, что видел сервис, которому можно скормить картинку на распознавание, но ссылку потерял. Найти не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, [gradientfinder.com](http://gradientfinder.com/)

Comment: Спасибо. Что-то он у меня вешает браузер на половине картинок :)